# How to make a multiple --scale dialog in yad or other alternative?

Tags: menu

Is it possible to make a dialog with multiple --scale in [yad](http://sourceforge.net/projects/yad-dialog/), or other alternative easily, can you help me?

I would like an interface multiple on/off.

Example:

[image]

**This is my script...**

```
#!/bin/sh
enable=0
disable=1

ret=$(yad --scale --value $disable --min-value $enable --max-value $disable --text "Enabla/disable sudo" --width=200 --height=100)

if [[ $ret -eq 0 ]]; then
echo 'enable'

elif [[ $ret -eq 1 ]]; then
echo 'disable'
fi
```

---

This is a script writed in python,I try to learn python, I do not know how to transfer values ​​to this script :(

```
#!/bin/python
from gi.repository import Gtk

class SwitcherWindow(Gtk.Window):

    def __init__(self):
        Gtk.Window.__init__(self, title="Switch Demo")
        self.set_border_width(10)

        hbox = Gtk.Box(spacing=6)
        self.add(hbox)

        switch = Gtk.Switch()
        switch.connect("notify::active", self.on_switch_activated)
        switch.set_active(False)
        hbox.pack_start(switch, True, True, 0)

        switch = Gtk.Switch()
        switch.connect("notify::active", self.on_switch_activated)
        switch.set_active(True)
        hbox.pack_start(switch, True, True, 0)

    def on_switch_activated(self, switch, gparam):
        if switch.get_active():
            state = "on"
        else:
            state = "off"
        print("Switch was turned", state)

win = SwitcherWindow()
win.connect("delete-event", Gtk.main_quit)
win.show_all()
Gtk.main()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've too have tried to use [`zenity`](https://help.gnome.org/users/zenity/stable/) and [`yad`](https://code.google.com/p/yad/) to accomplish GUIs but as soon as I wanted to do anything more complex as you're suggesting I've hit a wall where these 2 tools weren't really meant to do such tasks. They're sweet spot is more in very basic GUI elements and nothing more, at least in their current forms.

To do more complicated tasks you'll likely have to resort to an actual programming language such as Python, Ruby, or Perl where you'll get better access to the GTK+ libraries for creating the various widgets and graphical elements that it contains.

Another contender would be to use [GTKDialog](https://code.google.com/p/gtkdialog/). There's a nice tutorial that showcases what can be accomplished from this PCLinuxOS Magazine articled titled: [Creating a GUI with GTKDialog](http://pclosmag.com/html/Issues/200910/page21.html).